# Get fingerprint image from android scanner in my application for biometric encryption approach

Tags: android, encryption, fingerprint, biometrics

Android 6 fingerprint API prevent applications from getting a copy of the FingerPrint as mentioned bellow:

```
 The Android 6.0 fingerprint APIs do not provide any access to the 
 fingerprint material to apps.
```

However, my application requirements are:

1) Scan FingerPrint and get copy of it in my application. (to be used in generating encryption key.)

2) FingerPrint image should not be stored.

How can I reach my goal? any suggested fingerpring scanners/sdk ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. What do you mean with biometric encryption? What are you going to use to generate the key? Is sym or asym?

Comment: What's wrong with generating an encryption key using the normal secure random generator?

Comment: If you're planning on using a fingerprint as a password first think about how you'll change the password later (new fingers?), and that it's left on every glass & smooth surface you touch, like a laptop / monitor / phone.

Comment: I'm doing a master research in biometric encryption, however, my main point is I want to scan fingerprint in my application and get copy of it .. is it doable?

Answer (score 2):

Android M or Samsung or iPhone APIs only allow to verify current user against user of device.

There's some fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. These SDKs allow to get fingerprint image or template. Scanners are plugged on USB port so you can't charge tablet and use fingerprint scanner simultaneous. For instance:

- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/
- http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

There's also some devices with integrated fingerprint scanner and with SDK to get fingerprint image or template.

Comment: What devices???